# CSS: How to float left <ul> and align it to center <p> element in footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an adaptive 3-column footer using max-width 1366px and width:100%. Inside there are three columns, all floated to the left and with set width 33%.
In the center of each column I want to place a heading and an unordered list. The problem is that I want to align the heading to the center of the column and I want to align left the `<ul> <li>` items so that they begin where the heading begins, but are not aligned to the center.Funny thing is I have absolutely no idea how I should achieve it. In order to show you an example of the desired result I set padding-left:25% to each `ul` which sets the list items closest to my desired result, but of course it's not a solution.

**Desired result**

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="col">
    <p id="col-heading">HEALTHCARE SALARIES</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Top Healthcare Salaries</li>
        <li>Scholarship guide</li>
        <li>Student loan hacks</li>
        <li>Tuition</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contacts</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    <p id="col-heading">MOST POPULAR CAREERS</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Top Healthcare Salaries</li>
        <li>Scholarship guide</li>
        <li>Student loan hacks</li>
        <li>Tuition</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contacts</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    <p id="col-heading">FOLLOW HEALTHCARE SALARIES</p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
 /* FOOTER */

#footer {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1366px;
height: 360px;
background-color:#003C7A;
color: white;
}

.col {
width: 33.3%;
float:left;
padding-top: 50px;
}

#col-heading {
text-align: center; 
margin-bottom: 37px;
}

.col p {
text-align: center; 
}   


.col ul {

    list-style: none;

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: You need to show us the demo of the issue for debugging.

Comment: What you describe is not possible.

Comment: are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: Hey See My Plunker. May be It's helped you...

http://plnkr.co/edit/q3xIpRdZ48LyjorgUV4N?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```js
 // set first ul
 var fWidth = $('.footer.one').width();
 var hWidth = $('.footer.one header').width();
 var ulWidth = fWidth - hWidth;
 var ulWidth = ulWidth/2;
 $('.footer.one ul').css("padding-left", ulWidth);
 
 // set second ul
 var fWidth = $('.footer.two').width();
 var hWidth = $('.footer.two header').width();
 var ulWidth = fWidth - hWidth;
 var ulWidth = ulWidth/2;
 $('.footer.two ul').css("padding-left", ulWidth);
```

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1366px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer ul {
    padding: 0;
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
}

.footer ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <div class="footer one">
    <header>Heading Name Test 01</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nun</li>
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer two">
    <header>Heading Name heading</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
      <li>Aliquam feugiat nunc</li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <header>Heading Name</header>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I changed the code. I think you waited for this. Check this

Comment: You need to change colors and UL contents. Others are working fine. Please run the code and check. If not working for, let me know what is the problem with you.

Comment: Again, nope...the list must align with the left edge of the heading...that's the point.

Comment: That is pretty easy, remove padding: 10px; from .footer ul. I'll change it.

Comment: I don't think so...the padding is irrelevant.

Comment: Check now. No, padding should set to 0.

Comment: You're missing the point. The list should align with the left edge of the **heading** not the column.

Comment: Check now is this you looked for..?

Comment: Nope..you've just forced the contents to shrink to an arbitrary width. See - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MaBBpv Basically, what the OP wants *is not possible*

Comment: Yes I checked. I think here you need to use jQuery or Javascript. Because your headings are different. Means headings widths are not in equal length. So you need to get heading first and then you have to set the ul position. Is that the way you are expecting..?

Comment: @user2584538 Exactly. I want to align the list items to the headings.

Comment: I changed the code. Check the answer. This is what you are expected. Please not that this is jQuery. So, it is better copy this code and put into a HTML and check then. Because when you are running values are set via jQuery but when you re-size it setted values not going to change.

Comment: wow, @user2584538, thanks. Actually I think we solved it with a really simple css snippet:  
    .col { width: 20%; margin: 0 6.665%; float:left; } and it works

Answer (score -1):

You can put all your columns in a container, it adds automatically some padding aroud itself. 
Another way to do it is to add some columns offset.

Then you can add your list, and by setting their padding to 0 you will align them to the left :)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for proposing solutions and correcting my question, I'm new here apparently and have to post questions more carefully in the future and read the manuals :)
We solved the problem with really really simple CSS:

.col {
 width: 20%;
 margin: 0 6.665%;
 float:left;
}